# Linked number triplets

Tags: number-sequence

These triplets of numbers can be linked in a very specific way:

- 1, 32, 88
- 9, 19, 87
- 11, 93, 97
- 13, 28, 98
- 18, 91, 97
- 19, 87, 95
- 27, 38, 98
- 27, 88, 93
- 33, 38, 88

For the integers 1-99 inclusive, these triplets are not unique. What is:

1. the smallest such triplet?
2. the largest such triplet?
3. the only consecutive triplet?

(NB: only triplets with three different numbers are considered valid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the triplets can be linked in a very specific way:

> 1, 32, 88 becomes *T*HIRTYTW**O**N**E**IGHTYEIGH*T* - it can be written around in a circle with first and last letters linking up

The smallest triplet is:

> 1, 2, 8 = *O*N**E**IGH**T**W*O*

The largest is:

> 87, 97, 99 = *N*INETYNIN**E**IGHTYSEVE**N**INETYSEVE*N*

And the only consecutive one is:

> 8, 9, 10 = *E*IGH**T**E**N**IN*E*

Credits to J. Siebeneichler for most of the inspiration, if you upvoted this answer go upvote theirs as well.

Comment: If someone could add a visual, that would be great. I don't have access to graphics software at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The link between the numbers is:

> The first letter of the first number spelled out is the last letter of the second number spelled out, and the last letter of the first number is first letter of the last number.

<s>Given the third request, I think it's reasonable to assume that</s>

> the second number is always greater than the first, and the third always greater than the second.

---

Assuming that smallest and largest refer to their sum:

The smallest such triplet:

> one, two, eight

The largest such triplet:

> ninety-seven, ninety-seven, ninety-nine

The only consecutive triplet:

> eight, nine, ten... or nine, ten, eleven, so there must be another condition to the connection

Comment: Close. Your assumption is wrong and the largest triplet is wrong. Showing the triplets in exactly the right format should help you get the full answer.

Comment: See my clarification to the question. The largest is still wrong, and your other consecutive example doesn't work at all. The last point of my previous comment is very important (think spatially).